# Why Ajax works in two pages and doesn't works in third page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I work with `MVC 5`, I have `StartPageController` with action.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

And `Ajax call` for that:

```
function Logout(pageName) {
        if (pageName == "startPage") {
            $.connection.hub.stop();
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Builder/StartPage/Logout",
            success:
                function() {
                    if (pageName == "startPage") {
                            location.reload(false);
                        $.connection.hub.start();
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = "/Builder";
                    }
                },
            error: function (fdf) {
                alert("error logout");
            }
        });
};
```

I have `3 pages with Logout`. In 1 and 2 it all works well. But in the third, it is not working.

I have an ajax error. I tried to debug the code in controller. It works fine. But Ajax shows error.

Comment: So, what is the error? Try using the browser's debugger to see what is returned from the server, in particular the HTTP status code. Try removing your SignalR-related stuff to simplify your scenario.

Comment: are you using same code on all the three pages? if yes then please check the page hierarchy means pages are in same folder and check the url is same on all the three pages.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in `Ajax`?